# Dynamically add headers in table datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Is it possible to work with 2 rows in `THEAD` with dataTables?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        ## row 1
        ## row 2
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

In row 1 I need 2 single columns and one column with `colspan="3"`:

```
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
```

And in row 2 I need 5 columns:

```
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
```

But I have a case where I don't need 5 columns, but only 3.

Can this be generated dynamically?

**UPDATE**: I tried: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

But there's no good example how it's generated.

Comment: What facts speaks for two rows in the table header?

Comment: "But I have a case where I don't need 5 columns, but only 3." do you mean for both rows or just the 2nd - can you show examples for both cases?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of the [example link you posted](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html), it seems quite clear:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Rendering engine</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Browser</th>
            <th colspan="3">Details</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Rendering engine</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Details</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

*(Code lifted from link above)*

---

A word on viewing source code: In Firefox you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> to view the page source code. Even if there is heavy jQuery action on the page, the source code in that window will always be the original one without DOM modifications.

Comment: Ok this I understand, understood allready. Lets say I don't need column 'Details'. Can I change the headers within the .dataTable function? By changing aoColumns or a function...?

Comment: @iam: I have no idea. Why do you put data in the HTML that you do not want? Just leave it out and adjust the HTML accodingly. Or look at `fnSetColumnVis` at http://datatables.net/api. I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Please make it more clear.

Comment: If you don't want the 'Details' column can you not just remove it from the HTML? Basically in DataTables you must have a cell that will uniquely address each column (i.e. a cell that you can click on to sort a column etc). You can have as many colspans etc as you want, but there must be that ability to reference each column.